# GitPython: getting the latest tag of a remote repo

Tags: python, git, git-tag, gitpython

I'd like to be able to check what's the latest tag for a given repo (I'm using CPython here as an example).

The following works:

```
g = git.cmd.Git()
blob = g.ls_remote('https://github.com/python/cpython', sort='-v:refname', tags=True)
blob.split('\n')[0].split('/')[-1]  # 'v3.9.0a6'
```

because the `blob` looks something like this:

```
'bc1c8af8ef2563802767404c78c8ec6d6a967897\trefs/tags/v3.9.0a6\ndcd4 (...)'
```

But: **is there a cleaner way of getting the latest tag?**

Preferably using `gitpython` but any other package is also OK.

Comment: Without cloning : I don't think so. `git ls-remote` is the only command I know to get information on what is stored on the remote without cloning. I am going to vote to close this question, because you seem to already have a decent solution, and "a cleaner way" is obviously very subjective.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution provided by the OP is IMHO clean enough, and "cleaner" is very subjective.

Comment: "Cleaner" is indeed subjective, but what I meant was: supported by the `gitpython` or any other library such that it's well tested and supported by the community and less volatile than parsing. My solution went along the lines of: "oh, I think I see the tag in that string, I'll just try and extract it". I didn't verify how it would work in previous versions of git or will it be supported in the future -- something a library would do a better job of.
Does this make sense?

Comment: your question definitely makes sense. I just think you already found a clean enough answer.

Comment: Maybe you can contribute your solution to `gitpython` so that it *will* be tested and supported by the community?

Comment: I've created an issue: https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/1071 and if the response will be affirmative, I'll create a PR.

Answer (score 1):

`git ls-remote` is a stable and documented command of the git suite, so parsing its output is already a valid and stable way to get the info you need.
(I dug out a release note which specifies is was rewritten in C in version [1.5.4](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.5.4.txt#L58) (released somewhere in 2007-2008), which implies it already existed as a script in previous versions)

AFAIK, there isn't yet a python wrapper around it to find the existence or value of said reference through python methods, but the implementation of said methods would look a lot like what you wrote yourself.